# SQL query returns duplicate rows when adding one column

Tags: sql, duplicates

Hi i have a request that returns multiples id

```
SELECT sga.formations.id, sga.formations.titre, gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.specification, sga.formations.idTitre, sga.formationsTitres.description,
                         (SELECT        CASE WHEN dateDebut IS NULL THEN '2999-01-01' ELSE dateDebut END AS Expr1) AS dateDebut, sga.formations.dateFin, 
                     sga.formationsTitres.nonDispoClient, sga.formationsTitres.enLigne, gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.id AS Expr1
FROM            sga.formations INNER JOIN
                     sga.formationsTitres ON sga.formations.idTitre = sga.formationsTitres.id INNER JOIN
                     gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation ON gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.idDemande = sga.formations.idDemandeSGDF AND 
                     sga.formations.idTitre = gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.idTitre
WHERE        (sga.formations.idDemandeSGDF = 12544)
GROUP BY sga.formations.id, sga.formations.titre, gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.specification, sga.formations.idTitre, sga.formationsTitres.description, 
                     sga.formations.dateDebut, sga.formations.dateFin, sga.formationsTitres.nonDispoClient, sga.formationsTitres.enLigne, 
                     gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.id
```

I tried a couple of things i found on stackoverflow but nothing works. The moment i add **gestionDemandes.formation_sousFormation.id AS Expr1** in my select, duplicate appear.

Can anybody help?

Here's a [Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy162.png) of the results

I need to have 3 rows in my result. One with id 4176, 4177 and 4178

Comment: what do you mean duplicate? the entire record or just that field?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the duplicate add that same field to the group by. Most DBMS will just fail when you have a field in the select but not the group by without an aggregate function. It looks like whatever you are using just assumes you want a different functionality.

Comment: If there are different IDs in the same group, SQL will return one grouped row per ID, thus looking like a duplicate.

Comment: Since you have a GROUP BY, I can only assume that you have left out the key piece of information--that you are adding an additional grouping as well. Or else your query wouldn't run.

Comment: I'd use coalesce over the subquery.  for datedebut `coalesce (datedebut,'2999-01-01') AS dateDebut`  as far as the duplicates. Please edit the question to include a sample of the data that shows a "duplicate" use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to generate the table to display.

Comment: Have you tried adding a SELECT DISTINCT ?

Comment: I edited my first post with a screenshot of the results. Thx for the help

Comment: These are not duplicates - Expr1 is different in each case.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY`? I see no aggregation (`MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT`, whatever). What are you trying to achieve? Is it merely unique result rows you want to produce (which would be merely `SELECT DISTINCT`). Or do you really want to aggregate? Then which `EXPR1` do you want to show per group? You can simply add `MIN(EXPR1)` for instance to your select list.

Comment: The pseudo subquery `(SELECT CASE WHEN ...) AS dateDebut` makes no sense, you can just as well simply write `CASE WHEN ... END AS dateDebut`.